# How does actually 2 classes work in one program?

Tags: java

I probably have quite a big misconception, and I've been looking around the internet and still cant find the answer to my question.
So in java OOP, suppose I have 2 classes one called Main.java, the other Something.java, and because each classes both have their own entry point in their main method.

1. which one should I start the program with (like to call all the
   other classes in that program)?
2. And, if I were to use Main.java class, how do I call the whole things happening in Something.java? Like if that class was made to do its whole thing, with its own method, variables and all, and I'm just calling it all in the Main.java?

It's quite easy to understand theoretically, but in a program, not so much for me for some reason.

Comment: If each class has its' own entry point, then you have two programs. The fact that they share code doesn't change that. You would start `Main.class` when you want that program, and you could start `Something.class` when you want the other program.

Comment: `java Main` - will use the main method of `Main.java`

Comment: so what should i do? get rid of Something.java's entry point?
arent classes supposed to be called and used by the Main.java in OOP concept?

Comment: Instances of classes... `static` methods (including `main`) are not associated with any instances. The OOP concept would be `new Something().doTheThing();` from inside the `main` method in `Main.java` (but technically, the same OOP concept is expressed by instantiating `Something` from `main` in `Something`; because `static` methods don't involve an instance).

Comment: The `main` method is very unusual (it is static). Most classes are instantiated (constructed); the class is a template, used to create many objects that follow the same pattern. Your `main` method is like the conductor; it constructs other classes and calls methods on them: `Something mySomething = new Something(...); mySomething.myMethod(...);`

Comment: Thanks guys, you have cleared my misconception, now im a bit closer to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's you who have to decide your entrypoint class. If you decide `Main` to be entry point class your other main method will treated as normal method like other methods. Hence, you can call that in entrypoint class.

Example below:

```
public class MultipleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!! I must be executing");
        AnotherWithMain.main(new String[]{});
    }
}


class AnotherWithMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If you call MultipleMain class i.e. `java MultipleMain` then output would be:

```
Hello World!!!! I must be executing
Hello World
```

and if you call `AnotherWithMain` then `Hello World` will be printed per above impl.

Comment: Although this works, having multiple main methods in a project, and calling one main method from another main method is - in general - a sign of a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

One program must have one main method to start with. Because if you ran two main method using `java Your_Class` then you have 2 jvm instance.

look into some tutorial how to use multiple classes in one program .
[Using multiple classes in a Java program](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-multiple-classes)

Generally your main class will use other classes instance and static method. see the above simple example.